# Help with possible algebra equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

My friend has sent me this puzzle, but I’m terrible with Algebra, could someone please explain how to solve it step by step.
For example, how would I find the value of Q?

[Puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Jo5.jpg)

I wasn’t able to post the picture as my reputation is too low sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the second row, you have $K+K+K+K = 28$, which means $4K = 28 \iff \color{blue}{K = 7}$.
- In the first column, you have $Q+K+K+K = 30$, which means $Q+3K = 30$. Plugging in $K = 7$ yields  $Q+3(7) = 30 \iff \color{green}{Q = 30-21 = 9}$. Alternatively, you may have looked at the third row, which has $2K+2Q = 32$, which gets $Q = 9$ as well.
- In the first row, you have $Q+L+Z+Z = 46$, which means $Q+L+2Z = 46$, and using $Q = 9$, you get $9+L+2Z = 46 \iff \color{purple}{L+2Z = 37} \tag{1} $.
- In the fourth row, you have $K+Z+L+Q = 40$. Using $K = 7$ and $Q = 9$, you get $7+Z+L+9 = 40 \iff \color{purple}{Z+L = 24} \tag{2}$.
- You can solve the system of equations in purple by subtracting the second from the first, eliminating $L$, so you get $\color{red}{Z = 13}$. Plugging it in in either equation yields $\color{brown}{L = 11}$. Hence, all the variables have been found. All that is left is to calculate $X$ and $Y$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It is immediate that $K=7$ and $Q=9$. Then $L+2Z=37$ and $L+Z=24$ yield $Z=13,L=11$. $X$ and $Y$ follow.